# Pandemic on the Brink expansion in different language than the main game

Tags: pandemic, pandemic-on-the-brink

I have original Pandemic in my local language (Greek).

I want to buy Pandemic on the Brink but i cant find it in Greek.

I don't mind having mixed languages, but is there any other kind of problem that prevent me from having Brink in different language?

Comment: Make sure you get either the new or old version of On the Brink based on what version of the base Pandemic you have.  Otherwise the card backs won't match.

Comment: @bwarner Only the appearence of the cards will be different?

Comment: Yes, but since On the Brink adds a small number of cards to the existing decks, it is important to gameplay that the backs of the cards match so that you can't tell when one of the new cards is coming up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all the players know the expansion language well, there will be no problems.

Otherwise you may need a reference, paste-ups, or some other solution.

There should be no gameplay differences* between versions in different languages, if that's your concern.

*barring translation errors

Comment: I'm guessing that the card sizes and such would also be the same between versions?

Comment: @Thunderforge This is not true for every game, but it is true for Pandemic. As far as I know.